# update one element of array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('111111111111111111114444'),
  books: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('111111111111111111113333'),
      pictures: []
    },
    {
      id: ObjectId('111111111111111111112222'),
      pictures: []
    }
  ],
  // others attributes
}
```

What I need to do is to add an element to `pictures`. Keep in mind that I have the `documentId` which is the id of the document, and the `bookId` which is the Id of an element of *books*.

If I want to add the element `{description: "nice picture"}` to the document **111111111111111111114444** in the book **111111111111111111113333**, the updated document would look like

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('111111111111111111114444'),
  books: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('111111111111111111113333'),
      pictures: [
        {
          description: "nice picture"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: ObjectId('111111111111111111112222'),
      pictures: []
    }
  ],
  // others attributes
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your Books collection has an _id?

Comment: The books is an array of objects, which yes, they have an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- filter the "_id"
- map on books if `id=2` merge objects, with the pictures containing the new element
- else if not `id=2` dont change the book

*i used 1,2,3 for ids (its the same code)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251ad97f7e3c64c6511e170)

```js
update({"_id" : 1},
[{"$set": 
   {"books": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$books",
        "in": 
        {"$cond": 
          [{"$eq": ["$$book.id", 2]},
           {"$mergeObjects": 
             ["$$book",
               {"pictures": 
                 {"$concatArrays": 
                   ["$$book.pictures", [{"description": "nice picture"}]]}}]},
           "$$book"]},
        "as": "book"}}}}])
```

---

**Edit**

Query

- if pictures isnt't array(or dont exists), creates an empty array

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251ade6f7e3c64c6511e171)

```js
update({"_id" : 1},
[{"$set": 
    {"books": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$books",
          "in": 
          {"$cond": 
            [{"$eq": ["$$book.id", 2]},
              {"$mergeObjects": 
                ["$$book",
                  {"pictures": 
                    {"$concatArrays": 
                      [{"$cond": 
                          [{"$isArray": ["$$book.pictures"]}, "$$book.pictures",
                            []]},
                        [{"description": "nice picture"}]]}}]},
              "$$book"]},
          "as": "book"}}}}])
```

Comment: what if there is not an array yet? It would make concatArrays of null and another array which probably will turn out as null. We can't make $concatArrays of undefined. How can I solve this? I tried with $push but for some reason it doesn't accept it..

Comment: i updated for that case but if you have special cases of schema, ask about them in the question, because answer is based on the schema you sended that pictures was array always.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. Thank you

Comment: no worries its mostly for you to get better answers